# How to take a file as a form-field input without defining it as a Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, api

I have written a simple API for Tax Analysis through a ZIP file sent by our supplier using the `FastAPI` framework. (As you can see below). However, I had to start shifting my APIs to Django for some technical reasons. I have been searching for a way to input a file as form-data in Django, but all of them require a Model to be created for that, however, for my requirement, I don't need that file stored anywhere permanently, just temporarily in the memory for further analysis. Below is an example of how I was taking the file as  an input through FastAPI.

```
@app.get('/xtracap_gst/files')
async def gst(file: UploadFile = File(any))
```

Any inputs would be appreciated

**EDIT**:

I have managed to get the file uploaded in my memory but it returns a MultiValueDictionary and as per documentation, it is further handled by the UploadedFile Class of request.FILES. However, on running UploadedFile.read() it says `TypeError: 'property' object is not callable` . Please find my code below:

```
@api_view (['GET','POST'])
def gstAnalysis(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
        file = request.FILES
        file =  UploadedFile.read()
        print(file)
        return Response({'test'})
    else:
        return Response({'Test'})
```

Comment: you have `request.FILES` with all information about uploaded files - and you can use it.

Comment: django: [request.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) which has list of [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) which have `UploadedFile.read()`

Comment: @furas Thanks, I have managed to get the file uploaded, but UploadedFile.read doesn't work. Can you help me with that? I have edited my question with the update. Thanks

Comment: you didn't understand - You have list  `request.FILES` (even if you get only one file) and every element on this list is object `UploadedFile` which has function `read()` - `for uploaded_file in  request.FILES: print( uploaded_file.read() )`

Comment: I tried that, it says `'str' object has no attribute 'read'`. Here's my code `parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
        for x in request.FILES:
            x.read()
            print(x)`

Comment: sorry it is dictionary, not list. `for name, uploaded_file in request.FILES.items(): print( uploaded_file.read() )`

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. :) You have saved me a lot of trouble today. Merry Chirstmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it but ...

you should get dictionary [request.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) (even if you send one file) and every element in dictionary is a object `UploadedFile` and its `key` is `name` from `<input name=...>`. And `UploadedFile` has method `.read()`

```
  for name, uploaded_file in request.FILES.items(): 
      print( name )    
      print( uploaded_file.read() )
```